# is there an ios app development age rating official definition page?

Tags: ios, rating

Is there an official apple page explaining the age rating system for ios app development?

For example, specifically what qualifies as 4+, 9+, 17+ etc...

I saw online an image of a page where you can select radio buttons but I am not finding it on the developer website or an official definition of what is 4+ 9+ etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for App Store Help [App Ratings](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev269f11291):

```
Rating  Definition
4+      Apps in this category contain no objectionable material.

9+      Apps in this category may contain instances of the following content that may not be suitable for children under the age of 9:

        - Infrequent or mild cartoon or fantasy violence
        - Infrequent or mild profanity or crude humor
        - Infrequent or mild mature, suggestive, or horror or fear themed

12+     Apps in this category may contain instances of the following content that may not be suitable for children under the age of 12:

        - Infrequent or mild medical or treatment-focused content
        - Infrequent or mild references to alcohol, tobacco, or drug use
Simulated gambling
        - Infrequent or mild sexual content or nudity
        - Frequent or intense profanity or crude humor
        - Frequent or intense horror or fear themed content
        - Frequent or intense cartoon or fantasy violence
        - Infrequent or mild occurrences of realistic violence

17+     Apps in this category may contain instances of the following content that may not be suitable for children under the age of 17:

        - Unrestricted web access, such as with an embedded browser
Gambling or contests
        - Frequent or intense mature or suggestive content
        - Frequent or intense medical or treatment-focused content
        - Frequent or intense references to alcohol, tobacco, or drug use
        - Frequent or intense sexual content or nudity
        - Frequent or intense realistic violence
```